# Substring on CLOB field

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

We are trying to apply substring funciton in CLOB field to trim first 4000 chars. we are getting following error message.

Below is the query we are using:

```
select
cast(substr(field_name,1,4000) as varchar(4000))
from table_name;
```

Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: 8000, maximum: 4000)
>   22835. 00000 -  "Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion (actual: %s, maximum: %s)" 
>   *Cause:   An attempt was made to convert CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW, where
>              the LOB size was bigger than the buffer limit for CHAR and RAW
>              types.
>              Note that widths are reported in characters if character length
>              semantics are in effect for the column, otherwise widths are
>              reported in bytes.
>   *Action:   Do one of the following
>              1. Make the LOB smaller before performing the conversion,
>              for example, by using SUBSTR on CLOB
>              2. Use DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR to convert CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW.

Comment: Suggestion 2 looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 5):

Alternative using [dbms_lob.substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349):

```
dbms_lob.substr(clob_field_name, desired_size)
```

Doesn't require cast.

Comment: According to documentation dbms_lob.substr() counts in number of characters of the substr (not its size in bytes).

Comment: "Number of bytes (for BLOBs) or characters (for CLOBs)"

Answer (score 3):

The limit on VARCHAR is 4000 **bytes** not characters. If your database charset is a multibyte charset `substr(field_name,1,4000)` will be too long. (The 8000 in the error message suggests that each character is using 2 bytes, so UTF16 maybe ?).

Try :

```
select cast(substr(field_name,1,2000) as varchar(4000 byte))
from table_name;
```

But be aware that 2000 characters might take more than 4000 bytes (it depends on your database character set and on the text you're encoding).

Answer (score 0):

Try this below function.This should solve your problem.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(xmltype(CLOBColumnname),4001,LENGTH(CLOBColumnname)) 
FROM TABLENAME;
```

Comment: Tried 

SELECT xmltype(CLOBColumnName) FROM TABLENAME;

Got the below error:

ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'T'
Error at line 1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 301
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.